# Issue generating .zip files in prod (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, zip, linode

I'm using Linode as my hosting solution. I have a rails 3 app that dynamically takes mp3s (and other media) and creates a .zip file for download. It works fine in development but once i put it on my prod server the zip file still downloads but when i uncompress it, it creates a file called foo-bar.zip.cpgz

heres a code snippet from my controller -

```
   def get_zip
    t = Tempfile.new("#{@foobar.slug}-#{request.remote_ip}.zip")
    Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(t.path) do |zos|
      @foobardownloads.each do |foobardownload|
        extension = File.extname(foobardownload.foobardownload_file_name).gsub(/^\.+/, '')
        zos.put_next_entry("#{foobardownload.title}.#{extension}")
        zos.print open(foobardownload.foobardownload.url).read
      end
    end
    send_file t.path, :x_sendfile => true, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => "#{@foobar.slug}.zip"
    t.close  
  end
```

Comment: I also should mention that I'm using nginx.

Comment: You should use begin/ensure/end block to ensure that tempfile is closed in case of exceptions. Also, you should unlink tempfile (`t.unlink`) after closing it (again, in ensure clause).

Answer (score 6):

ok - did a bit of digging - this was actually an issue w/ rails 3 , nginx, & send_file. the solution is here:

http://www.novafist.com/2010/09/send_file-sends-0-bytes-to-client-in-rails/

the "quick and dirty" hack would be to open your production.rb file and uncomment this line

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
```

make sure the

```
#config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

is still commented out.

Comment: That change appears to work on Apache2 as well. I was having the same issues with zip files being recursively zipped. This change fixed things for me.

Comment: novafist site is down but solution is included in this answer. It's not a hack, it's configuring things correctly.